# Why use Time.current over Time.zone.now in Rails, when Time.zone is always set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

The documentation for `Time.current` says:

> Returns `Time.zone.now` when `Time.zone` or `config.time_zone` are set,
>   otherwise just returns `Time.now`.
>
> ```
> # File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb, line 36
> def current
>   ::Time.zone ? ::Time.zone.now : ::Time.now
> end
> ```

But when is `Time.zone` ever ***not*** set in Rails?

```
# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
```

I have commented out `config.time_zone`and I still get Time.zone equal to 'UTC' as it apparently sets that by default as the comment mentions. So then, what is the point of using `Time.current` over `Time.zone.now`?

PS: I'm observing this on Rails 4.1.16

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer is there is no difference except cleaner/shorter syntax if you are using `Rails` as is.

Time.zone_default gets initialized in `ActiveSupport::Railtie` via `active_support.initialize_time_zone`. More info on railtie initialization process [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-railtie-initializer).

My guess for reason of this check is that as a framework it is accounting for situation where someone removed this `active_support.initialize_time_zone` from their rails boot process. In that case `Time.zone` would be `nil`.